# The conditional Expectation of the Beta Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, beta-function

During a research project I was analyzing the shape of the conditional expectation of the Beta distribution, $g(t) = E[X\,|\, X>t]$ for $X\sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$.

Using numeric calculations, I got that $g(t)$ is linear when $\alpha = 1$ and concave for other values (both when $\alpha>\beta$ and vice versa). I was wondering if anyone has a reference or explanation for why this is so.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g(t)$ instead of $g(x)$ ?

Comment: The quantity your are looking at is the mean residual life. You'll find expressions for your case of Beta-distribution (of the first kind) in "Representing the Mean Residual Life in Terms of the Failure Rate" by Gupta and Bradley. However, looking at the article, it does not seem to be linear at all. Maybe you need to estimate the failure rate somehow.